# Update value in cached array in codeigniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, caching

I have a codeigniter application that using file cache. 
Inside cache file stored array that look like:

```
[id] => Array
    (
        [rating] => 1
    )
```

Where ID - current post. So, i writed little snippet that update vote count in database, but on the frontend i've got a problem with cache: when user voting inside database i have successfully updated vote count, but user can't see new result because i have cached data!

Maybe somebody know how i can to change my rating value inside my cached file? Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to delete the cache and recreate it, after updating your database :

```
// update statement here...
$this->cache->delete('vote'); // vote is the Cache ID
$this->cache->save('vote', $vote);
```

Comment: Yea, thank you for your answer! But there is a problem again! the app store ALL data in ONE cache file! So i have big array with all data about my content inside cache file! Any ideas? Maybe better to rewrite app to store data in a single file for every post?

Comment: It will be better if you do so, but if you can't for some reasons, you can read the cache and update the specific value you want, $vote = $this->cache->get('vote'); foreach on the $vote variable to find the value and update it, after that you can save the $vote variable again, $this->cache->save('vote', $vote);

Comment: You're right, i think, it harder to support in future and more hard for the server. Thanks again!